# How to grep JSON key's value in command-line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, aws

This is my JSON output for this command `aws logs list-log-groups` and from this I need the first "arn" value to be grepped.  How can I do this?

```
{
    "logGroups": [
        {
            "logGroupName": "alla",
            "creationTime": 1594638588652,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*",
            "storedBytes": 0
        },
        {
            "logGroupName": "mahi",
            "creationTime": 1594638580461,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*",
            "storedBytes": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently discovered a tool called [`gron`](https://github.com/TomNomNom/gron).

```bsh
gron <<'END_JSON'
{
    "logGroups": [
        {
            "logGroupName": "alla",
            "creationTime": 1594638588652,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*",
            "storedBytes": 0
        },
        {
            "logGroupName": "mahi",
            "creationTime": 1594638580461,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*",
            "storedBytes": 0
        }
    ]
}
END_JSON
```

```
json = {};
json.logGroups = [];
json.logGroups[0] = {};
json.logGroups[0].arn = "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*";
json.logGroups[0].creationTime = 1594638588652;
json.logGroups[0].logGroupName = "alla";
json.logGroups[0].metricFilterCount = 0;
json.logGroups[0].storedBytes = 0;
json.logGroups[1] = {};
json.logGroups[1].arn = "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*";
json.logGroups[1].creationTime = 1594638580461;
json.logGroups[1].logGroupName = "mahi";
json.logGroups[1].metricFilterCount = 0;
json.logGroups[1].storedBytes = 0;
```

This tool transforms the JSON notation into line-by-line javascript that is easily greppable.

```bsh
$ arn=$(gron <<'END_JSON' | sed -En '/json\.logGroups\[0\]\.arn/ s/^[^"]*"(.*)";$/\1/p'
{
  ...
}
END_JSON
)
$ echo "$arn"
arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:12345678910:log-group:*:*
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `jq`:

```
aws logs list-log-groups | jq -r '.logGroups[0].arn'
```

Output:

```
arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:929815623526:log-group:alla:
```

---

`jq` can be installed from the [`universe` repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository):

```
sudo apt install jq
```

---

`jq` is to be preferred for parsing `json`, but if `jq` is no option for whatever reason and you know that the format won't change, you can possibly use `grep -P` and `head -n1`:

```
aws logs list-log-groups | grep -Po '"arn": "\K[^"]*' | head -n1
```